# appending a script to head on both window.width and window.resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, window, append

what i need is to append a script if window.width >= 768, else, append another one if window.width is <768.

here is my initial script, which actually works:

```
function appendScript(stickname){

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript"; js.src = "site/js/" + stickname + ".js";
    head.appendChild(js); 
    }

    if ($(window).width() >= 768) { appendScript("stick");}
    else {appendScript("stick-mobile")}
```

this works, but it's of course not working on window resize. so as you shrink the browser window to less of 768px wide, for example, you have to hit refresh to make the script work again.. even worse: if you're on a small tablet for example, it doesnt switch scripts as you switch orientation.

i tried this:

```
function appendScript(stickname){

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript"; js.src = "site/js/" + stickname + ".js";
    head.appendChild(js); 
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) { appendScript("stick");}
    else {appendScript("stick-mobile")}
    });
```

this works only if initially resize your browser. which of course is not acceptable.
can anyone kindly help with this? thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think this will work. You won't actually "switch" scripts but add another one, so you will have the scripts for the two different sizes living in your page. You should better have one script that detects size changes and behaves differently depending on the size.

Comment: You should replace script elements. If you append new elements while resizing, after a while there will be a lot of them...

Comment: exactly! you are right

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me if this code, to place in a javascript tag, works ?

```
function appendScript(stickname){
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var js = document.createElement("script");
  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src = "site/js/" + stickname + ".js";
  head.appendChild(js); 
}

(function(){

  if ($(window).width() >= 768) { appendScript("stick");}
  else {appendScript("stick-mobile")}

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) { appendScript("stick");}
    else {appendScript("stick-mobile")}
  });

})();
```

And just a question: in appendScript(), shouldn't you also removeChild(...) the previous scripts ? And for that add a class on your script elements, to differentiate them ?

Comment: this works! but as you said, it keeps appending scripts as you resize.. yes it should remove the "old" one and keep stick mobile while resizing unless you reach the breakpoint.. how do we do that? thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

nobody answered but this may be helpful for others, a friend helped me out with this script and this seems to work (even if firebug behaves weird)

```
window.onload = windowload;
    window.onresize = AppendScript;

    function windowload() {
        AppendScript();
    }


    function AppendScript() {

        if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
            Include('site/js/stick.js', 'on')
            Include('site/js/stick-mobile.js', 'off')
        }
        else {
            Include('site/js/stick.js', 'off')
            Include('site/js/stick-mobile.js', 'on')
        }
    }

    function Include(filename, status) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (status == 'on') {
            script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = filename;
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            head.appendChild(script)
        }
        else if (status == 'off') {
            var scripts = head.getElementsByTagName('script');
            if (scripts.length > 0) {
                head.removeChild(scripts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```